# Computed property based on child components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is it possible to create a computed property that relies on child components data? Seems like a trivial task but I can't figure it out...

**foo component**

```
<template>
    {{ foo }}
</template>

<script>
export default { 
    computed: {
        foo() {
            return Math.random()
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**parent component**

```
<template>
    foo computed property sum: {{ sum }}
    <Foo v-for="n in 10"></Foo>
</template>

export default { 
    computed: {
        sum() {
            // return...?            
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using $refs in a computed property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531755/using-refs-in-a-computed-property)

Comment: @RoyJ "it's explicitly not recommended to use $refs inside computed properties as it is not reactive". How about keeping this open for a solution which is more in line with the docs?

Comment: `$refs` is the mechanism by which you look inside child components. There is no other solution open to you if you want to rely on child component data. The more Vue approach is to have the data based in the parent and passed to the child as props.

Comment: @RoyJ Props can't be used since you're not supposed to alter parent data in child components. Sigh....

Comment: You can signal to the parent when data should change, though, using `$emit`. The example you give doesn't have the data changing, so it's not clear how you need things to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can*, but it's a pretty unusual approach to things, so it's likely not the best choice for whatever you're trying to achieve.

Instead, you might keep the data in the parent and pass it to the component as a prop. If you use `value` as the prop name, you can get some nice clean syntax from `v-model`. (You have to use `foos[index]` due to the fact that [you can't `v-model` an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629509/you-are-binding-v-model-directly-to-a-v-for-iteration-alias), but in this case you're just generating an index anyway).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foos: []
  },
  computed: {
    sum() {
      return this.foos.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    }
  },
  components: {
    Foo: {
      template: '<div>{{ value }} <button @click="reroll">Change it</button></div>',
      props: ['value'],
      created() {
        this.reroll();
      },
      methods: {
        reroll() {
          this.$emit('input', Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  foo computed property sum: {{ sum }}
  <Foo v-for="index in 10" v-model="foos[index]"></Foo>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. I understand the concept, though I don't undestand a couple of details in the snippet. For instance, `v-model="foos[index]`. Is it equivalent to `:value="foos[index]"`? Also, you're emitting the `input` event from the child, but it's not listened to by `on('input'` in the parent?

Comment: `v-model` is a shorthand for [a special `value` and `@input` combination](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events)

Comment: Ooh... ok. There is a fine line between clean syntax and magic code :)