# How to assign v-model for each iteration

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have this object error thrown by an API (lumen)

```
{
"title":["The title field is required."],
"body":["The body field is required."],
"days_after":["The days after field is required."]
}
```

I then assign this error to `mess` variable and Im trying to output each of this error as individual alert with this code

```
<v-alert v-for="me in mess" v-if="mess" error dismissible v-model="mess">
    {{me[0]}}
</v-alert>
```

However, When I dismiss 1 error, all of them are dismiss/remove

Comment: What is `<v-alert>`?

Comment: @connexo : component from Vuetify collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**donMateo** has a good solution, but if your intent is that dismissing the message clears the message from the errors object, you can actually do that (sort of). You just need to `v-model` the individual row, not the entire `mess` object. (Also, you [can't `v-model` an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629509/you-are-binding-v-model-directly-to-a-v-for-iteration-alias) so it can't be `v-model="me"`.)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      mess: {
        "title": ["The title field is required."],
        "body": ["The body field is required."],
        "days_after": ["The days after field is required."]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.0/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vuetify@0.17.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//unpkg.com/vuetify@0.17.6/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <div>
      <v-alert v-for="me, index in mess" color="info" icon="info" dismissible v-model="mess[index]">
        {{me[0]}}
      </v-alert>
      {{JSON.stringify(mess)}}
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: ah, I was close, I did actually try ```v-for="(me index in mess)" v-model="mess.index"``` that was kind of stupid to access array key as object property, lol. Thank you so much

Comment: I needed to change v-for="me, index in mess" to v-for="(me, index) in mess" in order for this involution to work, using Vue CLI 3.

Answer (score 2):

v-model binding is responsible for visibility of the alert, so you need an boolean property for that. Lets change structure of your data a bit:

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data () {
  return {
    errors: [
      {text: "The title field is required.", show:true},
      {text: "The body field is required.", show:true},
      {text: "The days after field is required.", show:true}
    ]
  }
}
})

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <div>
      <v-alert v-for="me in errors" color="info" icon="info" dismissible v-model="me.show">
        {{me.text}}
      </v-alert>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

and voila! [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ypwqxq)

Comment: the errors are thrown by Lumen (Micro Laravel), I am very new to lumen and I'm not really sure how customize the error thrown to accomplish similar json data as your example, I prefer to just work directly with that json data