# proper use of Vue $refs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im attempting to recreate [this exact](https://jsfiddle.net/gehtwxeo/89/) inline editing functionality in on of my vue components. However, and I may be wrong, I see some of the syntax is outdated Vue, in particular the `v-el` directive being used. I've attempted to update the syntax like so:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    numbers: [{
        val: 'one',
        edit: false
      },
      {
        val: 'two',
        edit: false
      },
      {
        val: 'three',
        edit: false
      }
    ]
  },

  methods: {
    toggleEdit: function(ev, number) {
      number.edit = !number.edit

      // Focus input field
      if (number.edit) {
        Vue.nextTick(function() {
          ev.$refs.input.focus(); // error occurs here
        })
      }
    },

    saveEdit: function(ev, number) {
      //save your changes
      this.toggleEdit(ev, number);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="number in numbers">
        <span v-show="!number.edit"
              v-on:click="toggleEdit(this, number)">{{number.val}}</span>

        <input type="text"
               ref="input"
               v-model="number.val"
               v-show="number.edit"
               v-on:blur="saveEdit(ev, number)"> <br>
    </template>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

However I get a range of errors... any suggestions on how to properly execute this?

**Here is the Error:**

> [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: undefined is not an object
>   (evaluating 'ev.$refs.input')"

Comment: Why are you binding `ref`? Your component doesn't seem to have an `input` `data` or `prop` property. You probably meant to just use `ref="input"`, **not** `:ref="input"`

Comment: FYI, your JSFiddle example is using Vue 0.12.15. Is that correct? If not, what version do you want to use?

Comment: forgive me as i didnt paste my correct/current code, i updated the question code

Comment: and i want to use Vue 2, the most up to date

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Many things changed from Vue.js 1.x to 2.x. I will walk you through the changes necessary in that snippet of yours:

- `v-repeat` should be `v-for`
- Replace `v-el="input"` with `ref="input"`

  - Since you are using `ref="input"` inside a `v-for`, then `this.$refs.input` will be an array of elements, not a single element.
  - To access each single element, you will need an index (for the array), that's why you should include the `index` variable in the `v-for`: `v-for="(number, index) in numbers"`
  - Pass the `index`  instead of the `ev` to the functions, so you can get the`<input>`s later using `vm.$refs.input[index].focus();`

And that's pretty much it. After changes you'll get:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    numbers: [
        {
            val: 'one',
            edit: false
        },
        {   val: 'two',
            edit: false
        },
        {
            val: 'three',
            edit: false
        }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggleEdit: function(index, number){
        number.edit = !number.edit;

        // Focus input field
        var vm = this;
        if (number.edit){
            Vue.nextTick(function() {
                vm.$refs.input[index].focus();
            })   
        }
    },

    saveEdit: function(index, number){
        //save your changes
        this.toggleEdit(index, number);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <template v-for="(number, index) in numbers">
        <span v-show="!number.edit"
              v-on:click="toggleEdit(index, number)">{{number.val}}</span>

        <input type="text"
               ref="input"
               v-model="number.val"
               v-show="number.edit"
               v-on:blur="saveEdit(index, number)"> <br>
    </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the functionality and not the code design, I'd recommend you redesign it. I think you want to edit data, and the data shouldn't have to know whether it's being edited. That is the role of a component.

So let's make a component that lets you `v-model` data. The component itself has a span and an input. If you're editing, it shows the input, otherwise, the span. Click starts editing, blur stops editing. When editing starts, set focus on the input.

It takes a `value` prop. Its input element emits an `input` event to signal changes (per [component `v-model` spec](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Customizing-Component-v-model).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    stuff: ['one', 'two', 'three']
  },
  components: {
    inlineEditor: {
      template: '#inline-editor-template',
      props: ['value'],
      data() {
        return {
          editing: false
        }
      },
      methods: {
        startEditing() {
          this.editing = true;
          this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.input.focus());
        },
        stopEditing() {
          this.editing = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <inline-editor v-for="item, index in stuff" v-model="stuff[index]"></inline-editor>
</div>

<template id="inline-editor-template">
  <div>
    <span @click="startEditing" v-show="!editing">{{value}}</span>
    <input ref="input" :value="value" @input="e => $emit('input', e.target.value)" @blur="stopEditing" v-show="editing">
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: `v-for` on a component tag should have a `key`. Also, why not `v-model="item"`? Also, great answer ;)

Comment: It should have a key, but it's not changing, and I didn't want to mess with restructuring to have an `id`. `:key="index"` is no better, although it hides the warning. As for `v-model="item"`, [you can't `v-model` a `v-for` alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629509/you-are-binding-v-model-directly-to-a-v-for-iteration-alias)

Comment: this is a GREAT alternative!

Comment: @RoyJ ooh, didn't know about that `v-for` / `v-model` issue. Thanks!